# Objective-c: How can I get the real phone Country (E164) code (Not the Mobile country code - MCC)?

Tags: objective-c, country-codes

I'm trying to get the real country code E164 (for example: US = 1 Or Israel = 972) in obj-c?

for Example, The user entering his phone number: 0523333333 and if the User is from Israel i need it bring back: 97252333333 to send an SMS with nexmo.com

For now i can get the MCC (mobile country code) but its different from the real country code (Israel MCC is 425 and the real code is 972)

Comment: Hi, take a look at this control: https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMDiallingCode - I hope its useful. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want, get the calling code from the user's country, not from the iPhone settings. (WITHOUT having a header file)

You'll need `CoreLocation.framework` to run.

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

CLGeocoder *reverseGeocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[reverseGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
{
    if(error){
        return;
    }

    CLPlacemark *pm = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *countryCode = pm.ISOcountryCode;

    NSDictionary *dictCodes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"972", @"IL",
                                            @"93", @"AF", @"355", @"AL", @"213", @"DZ", @"1", @"AS",
                                            @"376", @"AD", @"244", @"AO", @"1", @"AI", @"1", @"AG",
                                            @"54", @"AR", @"374", @"AM", @"297", @"AW", @"61", @"AU",
                                            @"43", @"AT", @"994", @"AZ", @"1", @"BS", @"973", @"BH",
                                            @"880", @"BD", @"1", @"BB", @"375", @"BY", @"32", @"BE",
                                            @"501", @"BZ", @"229", @"BJ", @"1", @"BM", @"975", @"BT",
                                            @"387", @"BA", @"267", @"BW", @"55", @"BR", @"246", @"IO",
                                            @"359", @"BG", @"226", @"BF", @"257", @"BI", @"855", @"KH",
                                            @"237", @"CM", @"1", @"CA", @"238", @"CV", @"345", @"KY",
                                            @"236", @"CF", @"235", @"TD", @"56", @"CL", @"86", @"CN",
                                            @"61", @"CX", @"57", @"CO", @"269", @"KM", @"242", @"CG",
                                            @"682", @"CK", @"506", @"CR", @"385", @"HR", @"53", @"CU",
                                            @"537", @"CY", @"420", @"CZ", @"45", @"DK", @"253", @"DJ",
                                            @"1", @"DM", @"1", @"DO", @"593", @"EC", @"20", @"EG",
                                            @"503", @"SV", @"240", @"GQ", @"291", @"ER", @"372", @"EE",
                                            @"251", @"ET", @"298", @"FO", @"679", @"FJ", @"358", @"FI",
                                            @"33", @"FR", @"594", @"GF", @"689", @"PF", @"241", @"GA",
                                            @"220", @"GM", @"995", @"GE", @"49", @"DE", @"233", @"GH",
                                            @"350", @"GI", @"30", @"GR", @"299", @"GL", @"1", @"GD",
                                            @"590", @"GP", @"1", @"GU", @"502", @"GT", @"224", @"GN",
                                            @"245", @"GW", @"595", @"GY", @"509", @"HT", @"504", @"HN",
                                            @"36", @"HU", @"354", @"IS", @"91", @"IN", @"62", @"ID",
                                            @"964", @"IQ", @"353", @"IE", @"972", @"IL", @"39", @"IT",
                                            @"1", @"JM", @"81", @"JP", @"962", @"JO", @"77", @"KZ",
                                            @"254", @"KE", @"686", @"KI", @"965", @"KW", @"996", @"KG",
                                            @"371", @"LV", @"961", @"LB", @"266", @"LS", @"231", @"LR",
                                            @"423", @"LI", @"370", @"LT", @"352", @"LU", @"261", @"MG",
                                            @"265", @"MW", @"60", @"MY", @"960", @"MV", @"223", @"ML",
                                            @"356", @"MT", @"692", @"MH", @"596", @"MQ", @"222", @"MR",
                                            @"230", @"MU", @"262", @"YT", @"52", @"MX", @"377", @"MC",
                                            @"976", @"MN", @"382", @"ME", @"1", @"MS", @"212", @"MA",
                                            @"95", @"MM", @"264", @"NA", @"674", @"NR", @"977", @"NP",
                                            @"31", @"NL", @"599", @"AN", @"687", @"NC", @"64", @"NZ",
                                            @"505", @"NI", @"227", @"NE", @"234", @"NG", @"683", @"NU",
                                            @"672", @"NF", @"1", @"MP", @"47", @"NO", @"968", @"OM",
                                            @"92", @"PK", @"680", @"PW", @"507", @"PA", @"675", @"PG",
                                            @"595", @"PY", @"51", @"PE", @"63", @"PH", @"48", @"PL",
                                            @"351", @"PT", @"1", @"PR", @"974", @"QA", @"40", @"RO",
                                            @"250", @"RW", @"685", @"WS", @"378", @"SM", @"966", @"SA",
                                            @"221", @"SN", @"381", @"RS", @"248", @"SC", @"232", @"SL",
                                            @"65", @"SG", @"421", @"SK", @"386", @"SI", @"677", @"SB",
                                            @"27", @"ZA", @"500", @"GS", @"34", @"ES", @"94", @"LK",
                                            @"249", @"SD", @"597", @"SR", @"268", @"SZ", @"46", @"SE",
                                            @"41", @"CH", @"992", @"TJ", @"66", @"TH", @"228", @"TG",
                                            @"690", @"TK", @"676", @"TO", @"1", @"TT", @"216", @"TN",
                                            @"90", @"TR", @"993", @"TM", @"1", @"TC", @"688", @"TV",
                                            @"256", @"UG", @"380", @"UA", @"971", @"AE", @"44", @"GB",
                                            @"1", @"US", @"598", @"UY", @"998", @"UZ", @"678", @"VU",
                                            @"681", @"WF", @"967", @"YE", @"260", @"ZM", @"263", @"ZW",
                                            @"591", @"BO", @"673", @"BN", @"61", @"CC", @"243", @"CD",
                                            @"225", @"CI", @"500", @"FK", @"44", @"GG", @"379", @"VA",
                                            @"852", @"HK", @"98", @"IR", @"44", @"IM", @"44", @"JE",
                                            @"850", @"KP", @"82", @"KR", @"856", @"LA", @"218", @"LY",
                                            @"853", @"MO", @"389", @"MK", @"691", @"FM", @"373", @"MD",
                                            @"258", @"MZ", @"970", @"PS", @"872", @"PN", @"262", @"RE",
                                            @"7", @"RU", @"590", @"BL", @"290", @"SH", @"1", @"KN",
                                            @"1", @"LC", @"590", @"MF", @"508", @"PM", @"1", @"VC",
                                            @"239", @"ST", @"252", @"SO", @"47", @"SJ", @"963", @"SY",
                                            @"886", @"TW", @"255", @"TZ", @"670", @"TL", @"58", @"VE",
                                            @"84", @"VN", @"1", @"VG", @"1", @"VI", nil];
    NSString *callingCode = [dictCodes objectForKey:countryCode];
    NSLog(@"%@", callingCode);
}];
```